# HTML Canvas & Javascript - Triggering Audio by Selection (From Multiple Places)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a selection menu in my HTML canvas that I would like to trigger corresponding audio files. I have tried implementing this by declaring the images inside the `if (this.hovered)` & `(this.clicked)` part of the `makeSelection` function within the selectionForMenu prototype, such that on each new selection the selected audio file is redefined, but this causes problems like slow loading and overlapping audio. It is also problematic as I am trying to get the speaker button at the bottom of the screen to play the audio corresponding to the current selection too, so if it is only defined within that function it is not accessible to the `makeButton` function.

You can see the selection menu and speaker button in the snippet below. Each new selection in the menu should play **once** an audio file that corresponds to it (which I have not been able to add to this demonstration). It can be replayed by re-clicking the selection or clicking the speaker button, but each click should only provoke one play of the audio and of course overlapping is undesired. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
var c=document.getElementById('game'),
  canvasX=c.offsetLeft,
  canvasY=c.offsetTop,
  ctx=c.getContext('2d');

var button = function(id, x, strokeColor) {
 this.id = id;
 this.x = x;
 this.strokeColor = strokeColor;
 this.hovered = false;
 this.clicked = false;
}

button.prototype.makeInteractiveButton = function() {
 if (this.hovered) {
  if (this.clicked) {
   this.fillColor = '#DFBCDE';
  } else {
   this.fillColor = '#CA92C8'
  }
 } else {
  this.fillColor = '#BC77BA'
 }
 ctx.strokeStyle=this.strokeColor;
 ctx.fillStyle=this.fillColor;
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.lineWidth='5';
 ctx.arc(this.x, 475, 20, 0, 2*Math.PI);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.fill();
}

button.prototype.hitTest = function(x, y) {
 return (Math.pow(x-this.x, 2) + Math.pow(y-475, 2) < Math.pow(20, 2));
}

var selectionForMenu = function(id, text, y) {
 this.id = id;
 this.text = text;
 this.y = y;
 this.hovered = false;
 this.clicked = false;
 this.lastClicked = false;
}

selectionForMenu.prototype.makeSelection = function() {
 var fillColor='#A84FA5';
 if (this.hovered) {
  if (this.clicked) {
   if (this.lastClicked) {
    fillColor='#E4C7E2';
   } else {
    fillColor='#D5A9D3';
   }
  } else if (this.lastClicked) {
   fillColor='#D3A4D0';
  } else {
   fillColor='#BA74B7';
  }
 } else if (this.lastClicked) {
  fillColor='#C78DC5';
 } else {
  fillColor='#A84FA5';
 }
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle=fillColor;
 ctx.fillRect(0, this.y, 350, 30)
 ctx.stroke();

 ctx.font='10px Noto Sans';
 ctx.fillStyle='white';
 ctx.textAlign='left';
 ctx.fillText(this.text, 10, this.y+19);
}

selectionForMenu.prototype.hitTest = function(x, y) {
 return (x >= 0) && (x <= (350)) && (y >= this.y) && (y <= (this.y+30)) && !((x >= 0) && (y > 450));
}

var Paint = function(element) {
 this.element = element;
 this.shapes = [];
}

Paint.prototype.addShape = function(shape) {
 this.shapes.push(shape);
}

Paint.prototype.render = function() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.element.width, this.element.height);

 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  try {
   this.shapes[i].makeSelection();
  }
  catch(err) {}
 }

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle='#BC77BA';
 ctx.fillRect(0, 450, 750, 50);
 ctx.stroke();

 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  try {
   this.shapes[i].makeInteractiveButton();
  }
  catch(err) {}
 }

 var speaker = new Image(25, 25);
 speaker.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXg2I.png';
 ctx.drawImage(speaker, 162.5, 462.5);
}

Paint.prototype.setHovered = function(shape) {
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  this.shapes[i].hovered = this.shapes[i] == shape;
 }
 this.render();
}

Paint.prototype.setClicked = function(shape) {
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  this.shapes[i].clicked = this.shapes[i] == shape;
 }
 this.render();
}

Paint.prototype.setUnclicked = function(shape) {
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  this.shapes[i].clicked = false;
  if (Number.isInteger(this.shapes[i].id)) {
   this.shapes[i].lastClicked = this.shapes[i] == shape;
  }
 }
 this.render();
}

Paint.prototype.select = function(x, y) {
 for (var i=this.shapes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (this.shapes[i].hitTest(x, y)) {
   return this.shapes[i];
  }
 }
 return null
}

var paint = new Paint(c);
var btn = new button('speaker', 175, '#FFFCF8');
var selection = [];
for (i=0; i<15; i++) {
 selection.push(new selectionForMenu(i+1, i, i*30));
}

paint.addShape(btn);
for (i=0; i<15; i++) {
 paint.addShape(selection[i])
}

paint.render();

function mouseDown(event) {
 var x = event.x - canvasX;
 var y = event.y - canvasY;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);

 paint.setClicked(shape);
}

function mouseUp(event) {
 var x = event.x - canvasX;
 var y = event.y - canvasY;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);

 paint.setUnclicked(shape);
}

function mouseMove(event) {
 var x = event.x - canvasX;
 var y = event.y - canvasY;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);

 paint.setHovered(shape);
}

c.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
c.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
c.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
```

```css
canvas {
  z-index: -1;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  background: #9F3A9B;
}

img {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#speaker {
  top: 480px;
  left: 592px;
}

#snail {
  top: 475px;
  left: 637.5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>uTalk Demo</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='wordpractice.css' media='screen'></style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="game" width = "350" height = "500"></canvas>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='wordpractice copy.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What keeps you of keeping a global variable to the currently focused audio element?

Comment: How would I check the identity of the current audio file? Would it work to say, within the `makeSelection` function, something akin to `if (audio != Audio(linkToSelectedAudio)) {audio = Audio(linkToSelectedAudio)}`? If not, won't this cause the same problem of slow reloading described in my question (because the audio will be redefined in every frame)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want responsiveness with audio, forget about MediaElements, and go with the Web Audio API.
MediaElements (`<audio>` and `<video>`) are slow, and http caching is an nightmare.

With the Web Audio API, you can first download all you media as arrayBuffers, decode their audio data to AudioBuffers, that you'll attach to your js objects.
From there, you'll be able to play new instances of these media in µs.

<sub>*Beware, ES6 syntax below, for older browsers, [here is an ES5 rewrite](https://jsfiddle.net/rb0wcpxm/), also note that Internet Explorer < Edge **does not** support the Web Audio API, if you need to support these browsers, you'll have to make an fallback with audio elements.*</sub>

```js
(function myFirstDrumKit() {

  const db_url = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/'; // all our medias are stored on dropbox

  // we'll need to first load all the audios
  function initAudios() {
    const promises = drum.parts.map(part => {
      return fetch(db_url + part.audio_src) // fetch the file
        .then(resp => resp.arrayBuffer()) // as an arrayBuffer
        .then(buf => drum.a_ctx.decodeAudioData(buf)) // then decode its audio data
        .then(AudioBuf => {
          part.buf = AudioBuf; // store the audioBuffer (won't change)
          return Promise.resolve(part); // done
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(promises); // when all are loaded
  }

  function initImages() {
    // in this version we have only an static image,
    // but we could have multiple per parts, with the same logic as for audios
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = db_url + drum.bg_src;
    drum.bg = img;
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      img.onload = res;
      img.onerror = rej;
    });
  }

  let general_solo = false;
  let part_solo = false;

  const drum = {
    a_ctx: new AudioContext(),
    generate_sound: (part) => {
      // called each time we need to play a source
      const source = drum.a_ctx.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = part.buf;
      source.connect(drum.gain);
      // to keep only one playing at a time
      // simply store this sourceNode, and stop the previous one
      if(general_solo){
        // stop all playing sources
        drum.parts.forEach(p => (p.source && p.source.stop(0)));
        }
      else if (part_solo && part.source) {
        // stop only the one of this part
        part.source.stop(0);
      }
      // store the source
      part.source = source;
      source.start(0);
    },
    parts: [{
        name: 'hihat',
        x: 90,
        y: 116,
        w: 160,
        h: 70,
        audio_src: 'kbgd2jm7ezk3u3x/hihat.mp3'
      },
      {
        name: 'snare',
        x: 79,
        y: 192,
        w: 113,
        h: 58,
        audio_src: 'h2j6vm17r07jf03/snare.mp3'
      },
      {
        name: 'kick',
        x: 80,
        y: 250,
        w: 200,
        h: 230,
        audio_src: '1cdwpm3gca9mlo0/kick.mp3'
      },
      {
        name: 'tom',
        x: 290,
        y: 210,
        w: 110,
        h: 80,
        audio_src: 'h8pvqqol3ovyle8/tom.mp3'
      }
    ],
    bg_src: '0jkaeoxls18n3y5/_drumkit.jpg?dl=0',
  };
  drum.gain = drum.a_ctx.createGain();
  drum.gain.gain.value = .5;
  drum.gain.connect(drum.a_ctx.destination);


  function initCanvas() {
    const c = drum.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = drum.ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    c.width = drum.bg.width;
    c.height = drum.bg.height;
    ctx.drawImage(drum.bg, 0, 0);
    document.body.appendChild(c);
    addEvents(c);
  }

  const isHover = (x, y) =>
    (drum.parts.filter(p => (p.x < x && p.x + p.w > x && p.y < y && p.y + p.h > y))[0] || false);


  function addEvents(canvas) {
    let mouse_hovered = false;
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
      mouse_hovered = isHover(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop)
      if (mouse_hovered) {
        canvas.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      } else {
        canvas.style.cursor = 'default';
      }
    })
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (mouse_hovered) {
        drum.generate_sound(mouse_hovered);
      }
    });
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    checkboxes[0].onchange = function() {
      general_solo = this.checked;
      general_solo && (checkboxes[1].checked = part_solo = true);
    };
    checkboxes[1].onchange = function() {
      part_solo = this.checked;
      !part_solo && (checkboxes[0].checked = general_solo = false);
    };
  }
  Promise.all([initAudios(), initImages()])
    .then(initCanvas);

})()

/* 
Audio Samples are from https://sampleswap.org/filebrowser-new.php?d=DRUMS+%28FULL+KITS%29%2FSpasm+Kit%2F
Original image is from http://truimg.toysrus.co.uk/product/images/UK/0023095_CF0001.jpg?resize=500:500
*/
```

```html
<label>general solo<input type="checkbox"></label><br>
<label>part solo<input type="checkbox"></label><br>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this does, the code snippet is returning an error.

Comment: @JonathanConnell from which browser and which error (didn't tested in IE and this snippet uses ES6 syntax, and some new APIs which require up to date browsers

Comment: Works on Chrome. I like this answer a lot but due to lack of browser support and complexity I have accepted Jonas' answer instead.

Comment: Well it depends on what you call lacks of browser support, Yes, no IE < Edge support, but everything else is polyfiable / rewritable. You can always fallback on mediaElements for older browsers.

Comment: @JonathanConnell, [here is an rewrite](https://jsfiddle.net/rb0wcpxm/) for older browsers (tested under Safari 9 which doesn't support ES6. Should work in Edge too.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will definitely use this in subsequent projects. I've now accepted this as it is the more comprehensive answer.

Comment: And whats the usefullness compared to new Audio()?

Comment: @Jonasw an http cacheable data that takes only the memory necessary, a full control on trigger timing with micro second precision, an ease of use when you're in it. Audio.play will always have an delay, that you can't control. WebAudioAPI has its own high precision clock, and, on some implementations, is not even processed on the same thread as the main js one. Just try to spam your mouse click, you'll see that all clicks render an sound, check your browser memory usage in the mean time.

Comment: @Jonasw Then do the same with Audio. AudioBufferSourceNodes are tiny js objects, made to not consume anything so that you can create 120 of these per seconds. With Audio, you can't have this rate for too long.

Comment: @kaiido: wow. But its quite new right? ( not of any standard yet...)

Answer (score 2):

You could create an Audio Loader, that loads all the audios and keeps track of them:

```
function load(srcs){
  var obj={};
  srcs.forEach(src=>obj[src]=new Audio(src));
  return obj;
}
```

Then you could do sth like this onload:

```
var audios=load(["audio1.mp3", "audio2.mp3"]);
```

And later:

```
(audios[src] || new Audio(src)).play();
```

This will just load the audio if it isnt already in the audios object.

Comment: Thanks, this works well. Do you know how I might prevent multiple audio files playing at once with this?

Comment: @jonathan var current; then on play: if(current) current.pause(); current=audios["newone"]; current.play(); simply keep track of a possible running audio...