# How to record directly from a webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, mediarecorder, recording

I am working on making a little music app.
I want to be able to record the sounds made in the browser, without relying on the microphone.
So far, everything I have seen about the [MediaRecorder](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/mediarecorder) api suggests that it relies on the mic.
Ideally I'd like to achieve this goal without using an external library.

For reference, here is how I am making a really simple sound.

```
var congo = new Audio('http://www.denhaku.com/r_box/sr16/sr16perc/hi conga.wav');

var drumpad = document.getElementById('drumpad');

drumpad.addEventListener('click', function(){
    congo.play();
});
```

Thank you

Edit: To be clearer, how would I record the sound made by the code snippet I included, without relying on a computers built-in mic. For instance, lets say a user is making sounds with a drumpad and they are wearing headphones, the mic would be useless. Even if they aren't wearing headphones, they would still be picking up a lot of background noises. I want to isolate the sound being recorded, to just the music being made in the specific browser tab that a user has this application open in.

Comment: What do you mean "record" sounds in the browser? You're example code is for playing a sound, not recording it...

Comment: To be clearer. How would I record the sound, made by the code snippet I included, without relying on a computers built-in mic. For instance, lets say a user is making sounds with a drumpad, and they are wearing headphones, the mic would be useless. Even if they aren't wearing headphones, they would still be picking up a lot of background noises. I want to isolate the sound being recorded, to just the music being made in the specific browser tab that a user has this application open in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So far, everything I have seen about the MediaRecorder api suggests that it relies on the mic.

No, [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) API does rely on [MediaStreams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream), but these MediaStreams don't have to be LocalMediaStreams (i.e from [gUM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)):

You can get a MediaStream from [MediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) (`<audio>`, `<video>`)'s [`captureStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream) method, if the media loaded complies with the same-origin policy.

But this will return one MediaStream per MediaElement, and in your case it's probably not the best solution.

Instead, make the great jump to the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), which anyway is more suitable for such an application as a *drum-pad*.
The Web Audio API does have a [`createMediaStreamDestination()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamDestination) method which will return a [MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode), which will contain a MediaStream in its `.stream` property. Every other nodes you'll connect to this MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode will be aired in the MediaStream, and you'll be able to record it from a MediaRecorder.

Let's recycle this [drum-kit demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282474/html-canvas-javascript-triggering-audio-by-selection-from-multiple-places/44289845#44289845) to include a recorder:

```js
(function myFirstDrumKit() {

  const db_url = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/'; // all our medias are stored on dropbox

  // we'll need to first load all the audios
  function initAudios() {
    const promises = drum.parts.map(part => {
      return fetch(db_url + part.audio_src) // fetch the file
        .then(resp => resp.arrayBuffer()) // as an arrayBuffer
        .then(buf => drum.a_ctx.decodeAudioData(buf)) // then decode its audio data
        .then(AudioBuf => {
          part.buf = AudioBuf; // store the audioBuffer (won't change)
          return Promise.resolve(part); // done
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(promises); // when all are loaded
  }

  function initImages() {
    // in this version we have only an static image,
    // but we could have multiple per parts, with the same logic as for audios
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = db_url + drum.bg_src;
    drum.bg = img;
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      img.onload = res;
      img.onerror = rej;
    });
  }

  let general_solo = false;
  let part_solo = false;

  const drum = {
    a_ctx: new AudioContext(),
    generate_sound: (part) => {
      // called each time we need to play a source
      const source = drum.a_ctx.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = part.buf;
      source.connect(drum.gain);
      // to keep only one playing at a time
      // simply store this sourceNode, and stop the previous one
      if(general_solo){
        // stop all playing sources
        drum.parts.forEach(p => (p.source && p.source.stop(0)));
        }
      else if (part_solo && part.source) {
        // stop only the one of this part
        part.source.stop(0);
      }
      // store the source
      part.source = source;
      source.start(0);
    },
    parts: [{
        name: 'hihat',
        x: 90,
        y: 116,
        w: 160,
        h: 70,
        audio_src: 'kbgd2jm7ezk3u3x/hihat.mp3'
      },
      {
        name: 'snare',
        x: 79,
        y: 192,
        w: 113,
        h: 58,
        audio_src: 'h2j6vm17r07jf03/snare.mp3'
      },
      {
        name: 'kick',
        x: 80,
        y: 250,
        w: 200,
        h: 230,
        audio_src: '1cdwpm3gca9mlo0/kick.mp3'
      },
      {
        name: 'tom',
        x: 290,
        y: 210,
        w: 110,
        h: 80,
        audio_src: 'h8pvqqol3ovyle8/tom.mp3'
      }
    ],
    bg_src: '0jkaeoxls18n3y5/_drumkit.jpg?dl=0',
//////////////////////
/// The recording part
//////////////////////    
    record: function record(e) {
     const btn = document.getElementById('record');
     const chunks = [];
     // init a new MediaRecorder with our StreamNode's stream
     const recorder = new MediaRecorder(drum.streamNode.stream);
     // save every chunks
     recorder.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data);
     // once we're done recording
     recorder.onstop = e => {
      // export our recording
      const blob = new Blob(chunks);
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      // here in an <audio> element
      const a = new Audio(url);
      a.controls = true;
      document.getElementById('records').appendChild(a);
      // reset default click handler
      btn.onclick = drum.record;
      btn.textContent = 'record';
     }
     btn.onclick = function () {
      recorder.stop();
     };
     // start recording
     recorder.start();
     btn.textContent = 'stop recording';
    }
  };
  drum.gain = drum.a_ctx.createGain();
  drum.gain.gain.value = .5;
  drum.gain.connect(drum.a_ctx.destination);
  // for recording
  drum.streamNode = drum.a_ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
  drum.gain.connect(drum.streamNode);
  
  document.getElementById('record').onclick = drum.record;


/////////////
//Unrelated to current question
////////////
  function initCanvas() {
    const c = drum.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = drum.ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    c.width = drum.bg.width;
    c.height = drum.bg.height;
    ctx.drawImage(drum.bg, 0, 0);
    document.body.appendChild(c);
    addEvents(c);
  }

  const isHover = (x, y) =>
    (drum.parts.filter(p => (p.x < x && p.x + p.w > x && p.y < y && p.y + p.h > y))[0] || false);


  function addEvents(canvas) {
    let mouse_hovered = false;
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
      mouse_hovered = isHover(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop)
      if (mouse_hovered) {
        canvas.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      } else {
        canvas.style.cursor = 'default';
      }
    })
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (mouse_hovered) {
        drum.generate_sound(mouse_hovered);
      }
    });
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    checkboxes[0].onchange = function() {
      general_solo = this.checked;
      general_solo && (checkboxes[1].checked = part_solo = true);
    };
    checkboxes[1].onchange = function() {
      part_solo = this.checked;
      !part_solo && (checkboxes[0].checked = general_solo = false);
    };
  }
  Promise.all([initAudios(), initImages()])
    .then(initCanvas);

})()
```

```css
label{float: right}
```

```html
<button id="record">record</button>
<label>general solo<input type="checkbox"></label><br>
<label>part solo<input type="checkbox"></label><br>
<div id="records"></div>
```