# How to play the same audio file multiple times at once in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to make a JavaScript based game based around music. I'm trying to play some of the sounds as the player moves, but if the previous audio file has not finished, it ends up either cutting off the first one or just not playing the second. I'm using the audio.play() method.

```
notes.C2 = new Audio();
notes.C2.src = 'piano/C2.wav';

notes.D2 = new Audio();
notes.D2.src = 'piano/D2.wav';
```

```
if (l1.cats.x == 0) {
    notes.C2.play();
}
if (l1.cats.x == 1) {
    notes.D2.play();
}
```

Edit: I'm also not familiar with APIs and stuff so if possible I wouldn't want to use them. 
Edit 2: I just realized the problem is that the same audio file cannot be played over itself.

Comment: If you really are doing a game based on sound, then jump to the [web audio api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282474/html-canvas-javascript-triggering-audio-by-selection-from-multiple-places/44289845#44289845) you can find a little demo that may help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this thing

```
var audio1  = new Audio();
var src1  = document.createElement("source");
src1.type = "audio/mpeg";
src1.src  = "audio/Dombra.mp3";
audio1.appendChild(src1);

var audio2  = new Audio();
var src2  = document.createElement("source");
src2.type = "audio/mpeg";
src2.src  = "audio/(TESBIHAT).mp3";
audio2.appendChild(src2);

audio1.play(); audio2.play();
```

It work on chrome and firefox.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to post my edit in time but I realized playing the files at the same time was not the problem.

Comment: It's ok. I just want to give an example for you to solve if you need.